# Bash script check if a variable contains any of the words from a list of words

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Consider the following variables:

```
file_name="file-abcd-name.txt"
word_list="abcd efgh ijklmn"
```

**Question:** I want to have an if condition to check the file_name to see if it **contains any of the words given in the word_list**.
(file_name will be received from the input.)

```
if file_name contains any of the ["abcd", "efgh", "ijklmn"]; then
   some_flag=true
fi
```

I checked the similar questions but non of them have the exact answer to my question.

Comment: Hardcoded list or a dynamic one? If the former, solutions like `case file_name in *abcd*|*efgh*|*ijklmn*) some_flag=true;; esac` would be possible, and not just limited to bash but compatible with all POSIX sh implementations.

Comment: Note that your `word_list="abcd efgh ijklm"` isn't a list at all, but rather is a string with literal spaces in it. The right way to define a list in bash is `word_list=( "abcd" "efgh" "ijklm" )`, [which creates an array](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) -- that way your list entries can contain spaces, glob characters, and other things that have unexpected behaviors when used in a string that's expanded unquoted, and you don't trip static-checker warnings like shellcheck's [SC2086](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2086) when your code is being run through automated QA tools.

Comment: `grep` has an `-f` switch, just for that, as you can see in this excerpt of the manpage: `grep [OPTION...] -f PATTERN_FILE ... [FILE...]`.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

```
foo="simsalabim"

for val in "xyz" "sim" "abc";
do
    if [[ "$foo" == *"$val"* ]]; then
        echo "$val is in $foo"
    fi
done
```

Its output is

```
sim is in simsalabim
```

Comment: Maybe demonstrate with `word_list=( abcd efgh ijklm )` and then `for val in "${word_list[@]}"; do` to show that this works when the words to match aren't hardcoded.

Comment: with `word_list="abcd efgh ijklmn"` this is an example where `for word in ${word_list}` would work (notice no double quotes around `${word_list}`)

Comment: @markp-fuso, it would indeed (assuming a default IFS), but I hesitate to encourage anyone to teach it, because there are so many circumstances in which it _doesn't_ work; and `abcd efgh ijklm` is certainly not the OP's real data, so just because we know it works with their obfuscated example doesn't mean it works in the real-world case that data is intended to substitute for.

Answer (score 0):

With your given input/data structure. Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

file_name="file-abcd-name.txt"
word_list="abcd efgh ijklmn"

while [ -n "$word_list" ]; do
  first="${word_list%% *}"
  rest="${word_list#*"$first"}"
  word_list="${rest# }"
  case "$file_name" in
    *"$first"*) printf '%s is in %s\n' "$first" "$file_name";;
  esac
done
```

---

- Using an array which was mentioned in the comments instead of strings is a good approach with the shell like `bash` and others that supports that kind of data structure, the above approach would be an alternative your shell does not supports arrays, or if strings/variable assignment is the only option.